# C++ with LUA, object design

Tags: c++, lua, game-engine

This is sort of theoretical question. Let's say I want to make game with C++, and use Lua within it for game logic, AI etc. Do I make a whole object design/hierarchy in C++ or Lua? Or both? How does it work? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The only answer for such a broad question is: It depends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make the engine and performance-heavy libraries in C++ for maximized performance and you provide an API for everything in Lua.

If you have very game specific things, you're probably going to want to code them in Lua so you can reuse your game engine.

Whether you want to code AI in Lua or C++ depends completely on other factors and I cannot answer you objectively on that one. One option is to make utilities for AI in C++ and provide an API for them in Lua.

Let me recap:

- Before you code something in C++, ask yourself this: "Is this library general purpose for most games?"
- If the answer to the question is "No.", then you might want to code it in Lua.
- If the answer is "Yes", then you code it in C++ and make an API in Lua.

This is because the point of having a game engine is to make development of games easier in the long run and faster. You want it to have all kinds of general purpose libraries and utilities. It must be **reusable**. Separating game logic and general purpose libraries also makes it easier for you to change an entire game without messing up the core of it all.

Your question is not perfectly objective, so I'm giving an answer in favor of **performance** and **possibly better workflow**.

(I happen to be doing exactly the same thing.)

Comment: You're quite welcome. Game Engine development is something I've been doing for 8 months so far, so it was my pleasure to answer this question (: